# Microsoft Edge : After clicking search icon, a part of css is not supporting

Tags: css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

What is the other way to use Css for below same piece of code for Microsoft edge and Internet Explorer Browser. While Debugging, the below one Css code is showing in chrome but not showing in Microsoft edge Internet Explorer browser. Can anyone please suggest me.

```
.main-header .search-input:not(:placeholder-shown) + .search-button, .main-header 
.search-input:focus + .search-button {
    background: #00a0ff;
}
```

Html Code:

Comment: Can you post the related Html elements code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).Besides, I suggest you could try to add the CSS style separate.

Comment: I tried with separate also, but it is not working

Comment: posted Html Code.

Comment: Still can't reproduce the problem, it seems that your application is an angular application, and it also uses CSS framework, right? Can you create a sample using [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08sratg7/) or [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) to reproduce the problem?